How to create Socket io with TypeScript and react context

I'm trying to manage Socket.io as a react context.
I don't know how to give the type and default value when calling createContext().
I couldn't find any examples of managing with context even in the official documentation.
**
Below is the code I wrote.**

type SocketData is the type of data I am passing and has nothing to do with the problem I am trying to address.
ServerToClientEvents and Client ToServerEvents are interfaces used when creating io objects in the official document.
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

type SocketData = {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  userId: string;
  chatId: string;
  createdAt: string;
};

interface ServerToClientEvents {
  getMessage: (data: SocketData) => void;
}

interface ClientToServerEvents {
  sendMessage: (data: { receiverId: string; data: SocketData }) => void;
  newUser: (id: string) => void;
}

export const SocketContext =
  createContext<Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>>();

export const SocketContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:4000"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    currentUser && socket?.emit("newUser", currentUser.id);
  }, [currentUser, socket]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};


I tried giving it a type, but of course it didn't work.(It seems like there is no initial value.)

export const SocketContext =
  createContext<Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>>();


I tried the same with this code.
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

I really don't know how to give it a type and what value to set it to initially.

What's the problem exactly? Are you getting type errors? It's to understand what you are trying to do without a minimal reproducible example. When I tried to make one for you, I ended up with a lot of unrelated type errors https://tsplay.dev/Nanp0m. If you [edit] your question to include a complete and minimal example, you'll get much better help.

The problem with my code was a type problem.
The code you provided was exactly what I wanted.
Next time, I will ask a more precise question.

I think the primary problem here is that you type SocketContext as:
Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>

But then you try to pass it's value as:
<SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>

Which is an object type with a socket property like:
{ socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> | null }


To fix that you need to pass your socket directly as the value, and not part of another object.
<SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>

Then for the state that holds that socket, you need to properly set a type:
const [socket, setSocket] = 
  useState<Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> | null>(null);

So that it can start as null.
Same with the SocketContext:
export const SocketContext =
  createContext<Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> | null>(null);

With these changes, you should get no type errors.
See playground
